# Simple autocomplete in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, autocomplete, compare

Is it possible to compare user input after every keystroke(without hitting enter) with a list of strings?

example:

```
words = "house, mouse, music, halo,"
first_user_keystroke = h
second_user_keystroke = a
```

Then if only one possible match, in this case "halo", ad this string to variable.

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user

Comment: Maybe the [cmd module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/cmd.html) is what you want.